# What is the fastest way to check for nullable bool being true in C#?

Tags: c#, nullable

Wondering if there is a simpler way to check for a nullable bool being true.

I find myself doing code like this a lot which gets real bulky.  Any faster way to do it?

```
bool? x = false;
if (x.hasValue && x.Value) ...
```

Seems like there must be a clean faster way to check for true

Comment: It's not a duplicate because in this question the boolean is a nullable.

Comment: Thank you Hypenate.  It's nice that the stackoverflow police has police.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `GetValueOrDefault`:

```
if(x.GetValueOrDefault(false))
```

You can also use this with other types.

Comment: This seems to me like the best solution so I'm checking it.  I'd prefer that it not be such a long name and it would be nice if there was someway to say GetValueOrParam1(param1).  The way it is now, it seems a little vague because you could easily not know the default value. For example, is default value of string "" or null?  Be nice if I could say x.GetValueOrOther("") or something like that.

Comment: Actually, in this function you are passing as parameter the default value *you want* to have when the object has a null value, so in case of string you can choose whatever is convenient to you: an empty string or a null object.

Comment: Thanks Joanvo, exactly what I wanted.  Now, if they could only make it a couple characters instead of a block long method name.

Comment: I guess you can only shorten the function name by creating an extension method of your own which wraps that functionality (+ info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

```
if (x == true)
```

That should work and is the shortest

Comment: @MXD nope, that wont compile

Comment: Did not see the nullable part. My bad.

Comment: Surprisingly, it does compile. I wonder what the implication is if it's null?

Comment: @PeterKellner it is evaluated as false

Comment: @PeterKellner it does everything `GetValueOrDefault`, just internally so it looks less cluttered. Which is what I thought you were going for

Answer (score 7):

May be many developers are not familiar with this but you can use the [null coalesce operator (??)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173224.aspx), as shown below:

```
    int? x = null;

    // Set y to the value of x if x is NOT null; otherwise, 
    // if x = null, set y to -1. 
    int y = x ?? -1;
```

and for condition check :-

```
if (nullableBool ?? false) { ... }
```

and another option is [GetValueOrDefault Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (nullableBool.GetValueOrDefault(false)) 
{
}
```

Comment: What's interesting, the compiler compiles the `??` operator into a call to *GetValueOrDefault*. So, in performance, they are equal; in beauty, the coalesce operator is nicer. ☺